# Advice for shorter toe clips

Tags: pedals, toe-straps-clips, toe-overlap

I ride a road bike daily for commuting (~2.5 miles) and I like having toe clips (cages, straps, whatever other name they go by) so that I don't have to use special bike shoes.  My bike came with toe clips, but when the plastic on those finally busted, it was time for a new set.  I ended up getting some Wellgo pedals that came with toe clips, and they work great except for the fact that they are too long - with the wrong combination of pedal position while turning the front wheel, they will actually collide with the tire.  This is not only annoying, but dangerous (I have had two minor falls from it while I'm trying to find another solution).

In shopping around for toe clips online, I seem to only find ones that look similarly long to the ones I got (interestingly, this length is almost never specified in the product details), or they are very short and much more minimal, with no strap that goes over the mid-foot (I think called a "half toe clip").  Can anyone recommend a shorter toe clip with a full strap, or a better way I should be searching for these?  I am confused by the lack of results for a very similar product that just has a shorter length from the front of the toe to the front of the pedal (or equivalently, to the center of the pedal).

[image: interference with toe clip and front tire]

[image: front of toe clip to center of pedal is approximately 4-1/4"]

Comment: have you considered fixie style velcro straps instead of clips? Much more adjustable. Under 20 bucks.

Comment: Thing is, it doesn't _look_ like it's too long; it appears to be holding your foot in the correct position.  Maybe your feet are too long? :)

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley I do like having the front stop for the toe of my shoe that is provided by the style I'm showing here, and I feel like this style distributes the pull force a bit more than a single strap would.  Basically if I could find a shorter version that would be my ideal solution, I'm just having trouble finding that.  But thanks I'll look into straps if I don't find something else.

Comment: @DavidW You mean that it places the ball of my foot over the center of the pedal?  These are pretty close, but it does feel a bit far forward.  If I scoot my foot back 1" (all that's really needed to fix this issue) it feels like even better placement for my foot on the pedal.  Pretty normal feet length-wise, wear a size 10.5 shoe.

Comment: Other fixes, try pointing your toe down a little, and also learn to coast when turning.  Toe Overlap has been a thing for a long time.

Comment: My recommendation would be to get some good (~$50 US) mountain bike flat pedals with good pins. You're feet will stick to them plenty, you'll be able to pull back and push forward on the pedals thank to the grip from the pins, and you won't have to faff with the clips and straps ever again.

Answer (score 3):

Toe clips come in various lengths, since obviously toe clips sized for a big guy with size 46 shoes (like me) (== US 13) wouldn't work for a petite woman with size 36 shoes (== US women's 6).

The [toe clips page](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/s?q=toe%2Bclips&cat=direct) on Chain Reaction Cycles shows very poor stock, but I did find [this page at a US shop](https://www.benscycle.com/mks-chrome-twin-deep-steel-toe-clips/toe_clip__strap_mks_deeptwinsteel_311/product) which has medium sized ones in stock.  According to the sizing chart further down that page, they nominally fit men's sizes 5-8, but would almost definitely be shorter than what you have.

Additionally, since they are steel, if you are willing to put some work into it you could probably adjust them somewhat.

Note also that Criggie is correct and you should try adjusting your foot position when you turn.  I used to consciously rotate my pedals so my outside foot was down when going into a turn; now it is a purely automatic action.

Answer (score 2):

From the picture it looks like your foot is in the correct place.

Foot placement is about getting your foot in the correct place on the pedal - not if it hits the front wheel.

Here is how your foot should be on the pedal
[image]
[How to Fit a Bicycle](https://blog.bikefit.com/how-to-fit-a-road-bicycle/)

Roughly speaking, the ball of your foot should be directly above the axle of the pedal.

With your foot in the right place it will still hit the front wheel. As the comments mention and as DavidW says you will need to change how you ride to prevent your foot from hitting the front wheel. When you go into a turn right foot, or left foot down.

Comment: It is partly bike-dependent too, though.  While on my road bike my foot would always conflict with the wheel did I not move it out of the way, my touring bike (longer wheelbase) would just touch.  Had I a smaller foot I could probably turn on the touring bike without adjusting my foot position.

Comment: It's 100% bike-dependent. This bike has a relatively short front center for the rider. I've had a bike with dangerous toe overlap, and others with very little.